# Lagrangian Multipliers of Two Equivalent Constrained Problems

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given an convex optimization problem with multiple linear inequality constraints. Applying a strictly increasing function to both sides of the constraints yields an equivalent problem. If both problems are solved with the method of Lagrangian multipliers, is it possible to use the multipliers of one problem to estimate that of the other?

I think at least the multiplers corresponding to the same constraints should take zero simultaneously. Could I expect more?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the function you are applying to both sides? Giving a concrete example might help.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I want to apply the sigmoid function or the normal cdf. Also the orginal problem is a quadratic programming.